# How to detect whether postback originated from outside of particular div (client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Is there any way to detect postback (full/partial) originated from outside of a particular Panel (HTML DIV)? I would like to handle it in client side since I am planning to prompt the user in window.onbeforeunload event.
Thanks for your suggestion!!!

Comment: Can you just attach an event handler to the ones that *are* inside the div (or the reverse, if absolutely needed, depending on how many) and track the submit event that way?

Comment: Custom event using jquery defo...

Comment: Could you give me some examples?

Answer (score 0):

what about add some kind of prefix to the fields for the div 
or 
split it to many forms for each area(div)

..